# How to ascertain from the users if performance tuning has had the desired effect

Tags: testing, web-applications, performance, winforms, release

So you've made some code changes that should hopefully speed up some part of an application. But there is just one problem - you don't know how it will perform in live.

Different networks, different machines, different memory, different configuration, different times of day, different users, different server loads etc etc etc

So...

(a) Do you ask them if that bit of the application has got faster?

(b) Do you ask them to monitor that part of the application?

Or...

(c) Do you just ask them to see if they notice any difference in the application in general? After all, you can't be 100% sure you haven't affected something else.

Each of these approaches would seem to have problems (I know this as I've tried them all):

(a) You're asking a leading question. Before such a fix goes life, there is an emperor's new clothes scenario. The developer believes the code should be faster so there is some kind of crusade to get everyone believing it before it goes live. So...it goes live. Some people say it is faster, some slightly slower and others about the same. What then?

(b) Again: Some people say it is faster, some slightly slower and others about the same. What then?

(c) You're no longer asking a leading question, but you start getting hit with a whole torrent of issues that people have known about for months (maybe years) but you've now opened Pandora's box. How can you be sure which if these (if any) are new issues?

Or maybe I should be asking different questions entirely. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

No doubt there are processes leading up to this point that could potentially be improved. But the nub of the question is this:

The change is tested and has been put live. You have a myriad of stats to prove the changes should improve performance. Your boss has given the stats a once over but now wants to make sure the users are happy before signing off the release. What question(s) should you be asking the users?

Comment: About the code performance: profiling on at least the most common hard- and software setups. About Pandora's box: issue tracker.

Comment: I don't see the issue you are facing. Either a speed-up was requested by at least one customer. Then you should ask them to measure whatever task they are doing before and after. Or it is strictly for good practice; then you can write the pre-change and post-change tests and proflings yourself. Which is it?

Comment: @thorstenmüller We of course have a variety of test kit, but there are far too many permutations to hope to test even a fraction of what is out in the estate...

Comment: @KilianFoth Both. Some customers report speed issues but to those customers who haven't, it would be a behind the scenes change (e.g. SP or mid-tier). In either case we'd want to check that all customers are happy with the change.

Comment: If your performance enhancements are that fragile towards setups, maybe you have a case of premature optimization. There is not really much sense in asking people, especially if the answers are that ambiguous that they can't say if it changed and on one and the same setup some people say it's faster and others it's slower. btw: for your point c) unit tests may help to ensure that changes don't affect other parts of the application.

Comment: Yes, for point c) these are of course what Donald Rumsfeld would call "Unknown unknowns". Clearly a unit test has been missed in testing for these even to come to light, but once they do it is a fait accompli...

Comment: This is what profiling tools are for.  You have already have a baseline.  Just compare it to your changes.  If something is 10% faster on configuation A it will be faster on Configuration B.

Comment: If only it were that simple. Take SQL Server. As any DBA/DB developer worth their salt will tell you: Query cost is a product of CPU & IO. You might notice the cost goes down when you tune the SQL but then you run it and sometimes it will actually take longer. Also understand that this assumes the same query plan will always be executed. In reality however, it could differ as the spread of data is different at each customer site. The point I'm making is that if I could rely 100% on what the profilers are telling me, I wouldn't be asking this question at all.

Comment: surely _you_ should be monitoring it? Is that possible? I mean, what if your change actually makes things slower?

Comment: Not really. Just in the software we're about to release - our customer base is 500 sites running this part of the software 5 times a day with an average of 5 users. Our pilot period is typically 2 weeks. That is 175,000 iterations. We also have about 50 other changes going live. Mining this sort of data volume just isn't practical.

Comment: You cannot rely upon user feedback for this sort of thing. If you do not have a way to test/evaluate/profile your code in a controlled environment to collect hard data, then you may need to build instrumentation & reporting into the application itself to send statistics back to a central point for analysis (similar to how MS offers to collect anonymous "user experience" information in some of their products).

Comment: Again, theoretically correct, but practical? I'm not so sure. Don't forget, these are performance changes we're doing here - not some annoying bug that crops up now and then. Adding logging/tracing/profiling/debug or whatever you want to call it to everything just isn't realistic. Especially when you're not warned about what needs to be tracked in advance.

Comment: If as the developer(s) you can't even quantify the performance-sensitive areas of the application, you've already lost. How have you gotten this far in the development process without doing any performance testing, monitoring or profiling in your own internal testing?

Comment: I believe I've covered this in my edit.

Comment: @RobbieDee - you're making references to other comments. You should indicate either the user or what you're commenting on. They don't link up like a chat site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What question(s) should you be asking the users?

> Here is the next version of our program.  Please report any unexpected behavior.

Unless your users are using stopwatches, or your program has some very long-running processes, users are unlikely to be able to provide anything but subjective feedback.  And for optimization I'd be more worried about behavior not caught by your automated tests than an uneven speed increase.

Comment: A few smoke tests aside, this is our normal approach but management do like to tick those boxes...

Comment: Thank you for being the only one to actually understand (and more importantly) answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

You should concern yourself with data rather than subjectivity. Thus you should be monitoring/measuring/profiling to determine improvements. That monitoring needs to be in both production and test (and dev) environments.

Ideally, you shouldn't be optimizing anything until *after* you see the results of performance. Otherwise you risk a "premature optimization" which doesn't improve anything meaningful and perhaps was a waste of time and money. It is very easy to see a piece of code and think, "This is terrible, it will never perform well." only to find out later that it is only executed 1% of the time and the real bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: But, perception is everything here. After all, an application doesn't load faster because there is a splash screen - it is just a visual distraction to make the user believe otherwise. In my original question, I noted the scenario where it was believed that there was a speed improvement but also a process of propaganda to make this enhancement seem more evident to the user. Fully with you on your 2nd point (+1), tuning should be very much secondary to getting the thing working.

Comment: This answers it. If you can't assess the performance through load testing or profiling then you can't optimize it. Not with any certainty.

Comment: @Rig +1 - when I did Testing 101 all those years ago, this was (I remember) a very difficult lesson. For complex systems, you can't hope to test every case so have to be satisfied with a representative sample...

Comment: Good point. I didn't account for the user perception aspect of it. A splash screen is a great example. But even so, I think that measuring is key. Better to make the experience demonstrably faster in some way rather than trying to convince your users to "trust me, it's faster now." Someone might benchmark it and complain otherwise. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a configuration switch to choose between old and new coding and put it into the production system. Run it one week with each setting, measure, and compare.

Comment: This is something I have resorted to recently for exactly this reason. The feedback we're getting is mixed and the data can be skewed this way and that. Often much better to have such a switch and let the mob decide...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not measure performance in a development environment, before and after fixes? If it's 20% faster, it's usually safe to assume it'll be 20% faster in production too.

You should usually be able to find out quite easily the main bottlenecks in your infrastructure from past experience (or experience of other developers) and take that into consideration when profiling.

Comment: We can of course do whatever we like in development/test but for the reasons I've already outlined, this doesn't always scale outside the development office/lab.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you are involving users as testers, don't do this.

Your question is quite valid - how does an app perform once it gets to the "real world", with real world CPUs, user load, data volumes... but once you ask this question, you need to get some objective performance figures and users are never going to be much use for those.

So you need to emulate the user load, in a QA or performance test environment. Get a representation of the end-user environment, get some automated test tools that can hammer your system as if 10, or 10,000 users were using it, populate the data sets with masses of dummy data. Then you can run your tests and get some meaningful data. Then you can also re-run your tests with a new version of your system and see what differences there are.

Comment: This takes place as part of pilot where the software is released to a limited number of sites. Sometimes, this is as UAT whilst sometimes this is in addition to UAT. Obviously it would be a bad idea for us to just test it and throw it over the wall to thousands of users and devices.